--experimental-https not working in nextjs
I have a nextjs project which to test locally i need to run on on https, i have seen there is a --experimental-https command but when i run it i am getting
Unknown or unexpected option: --experimental-https

my project is "next": "14.2.3"
even when i create a new app i still get the warning, infact i also get a warning
The `app` directory is experimental. To enable, add `appDir: true` to your `next.config.js` configuration under `experimental`. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/experimental-app-dir-config

and i have to add a next.config.js with
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    experimental: {
      appDir: true,
    }
  }
   
  module.exports = nextConfig

I have tried updating next js but feel i must be doing something wrong.
Any suggestions would be appriciated.

To run Next.js server locally on HTTPS, you should run this command in the terminal:
next dev --experimental-https

or change the dev script in package.json to this:
"dev": "next dev --experimental-https"}

and after that in terminal you can run npm run dev.

my op says when i run that i get "Unknown or unexpected option: --experimental-https"

I had to remove all traces of node.js and then re install it (even thought i already had the latest version installed)
